# How to specify JSON node property values when parsing/iterating in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

**TL;DR How do I specify a specific JSON node property within Azure Logic Apps' *ParseJSON > For Each* step, when the designer only gives me access to the parent nodes?**

I'm building a Logic App that:

1. Receives and parses a list of people as JSON data from an external system
2. Constructs a new JSON file with different structure
3. Posts the new file to a second external system

The JSON response from item 1 has this structure:

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Message": "Completed",
    "Result": [
        {
            "EmployeeId": {
                "DisplayValue": "PW123",
                "FieldHistory": []
            },
            "EmailId": {
                "DisplayValue": "*****.*****@******.co.uk",
                "FieldHistory": []
            }
        },
        {
            "EmployeeId": {
                "DisplayValue": "PW789",
                "FieldHistory": []
            },
            "EmailId": {
                "DisplayValue": "*****.*****@******.co.uk",
                "FieldHistory": []
            }
        },
        .... removed for brevity
    ]
}
```

Within the designer, if I add a `Data Operations > Parse JSON > For Each` step, it lets me specify the properties, but at too high a level:

[image]

Notice the designer gives me `EmployeeId`, but I actually need `EmployeeId.DisplayValue`, which is both properties and their values in JSON format, rather than a simple string containing only the EmployeeId or EmailId values.

Can the JSON be read at the deeper level I require using the designer?

Comment: Logic App introduced a new connector: inline code. It could be helpful in your case: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/inline-code-for-azure-logic-apps-is-in-public-preview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you can do something in the lines of `Parse_JSON()['EmployeeId']['DisplayValue']` <-- this is probably not the exact match, but the syntax is something like that.

They way you do this is that you either write it in code view or in the designer you start on an expression, add the blanks with dynamic content and finish by adding the ['DisplayValue'] tag.

Comment: After a TON of messing about in the editor/code, I finally found a solution from which your answer helped.  I've posted my findings to help others, but will accept your answer in the meantime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To support the input by AdAstra and provide a canonical answer for future reference...

The `ForEach` block was misleading, and wasn't actually required.  Instead a `Select` block was required, but which then had to be edited in Code View (as advised by @AdAstra) to cherry-pick the desired fields:

[image]

[image]

<del>I still need to figure out wrapping the output in my desired structure, and will update when that's solved.</del>  It turns out that reforming the JSON into a new structure is also super-simple thanks to code view.  I just specified my desired output around the existing logic:

```
             "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Result']",
             "select": {
                 "Option1": "Value1",
                 "Option2": "Value2",
                 "People": [
                     {
                         "Email": "@item()['EmailId']['DisplayValue']",
                         "FirstName": "@item()['FirstName']['DisplayValue']"
                     }
                  ]
             }
```

**Note that Designer View does not allow for modifications to the more complex selections after specifying them in code.**